# Django test Client simulate logged in user

Tags: django, django-testing

I am new to Django test Client. I want to test a view that uses `@login_required` . I was wondering if I can do that using the simple `Client()` like this:

```
>>> from django.test import Client
>>> c = Client()
>>> r = c.get("/libros/nuevo_libro/perfil/farseer/")
```

But, of course, the response is always a 302:

```
>>> r.status_code
302
```

Cause the `@login_required` decorator redirects it to the login page.

Is it possible to simulate in this kind of tests that the user is logged in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The test client has a [`login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.login) method.

```
c = Client()
c.login(username='fred', password='secret')
response = c.get("/libros/nuevo_libro/perfil/farseer/")
```